# Does project tango dev tablet have pressure sensor?

Tags: google-project-tango

https://store.google.com/product/project_tango_tablet_development_kit
Does anyone who has the development happen to know if it supports Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE?

(I do not see it listed as one of the features, but have an application that needs pressure).

Answer (score 1):

Tango device does include the pressure sensor.
You can check the pressure sensor reading by using any android sensor test app on the Play Store.
My guess is that it should be good for normal sensor type in android.
But I have never seen any app using this feature before. You should have a try.